# Conditional template doesn't seem to work

Tags: polymer

I have the following in a polymer component:

```
<dom-module id="ws-auth">
<template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{screen.initial}}">
        <a on-click="doLocalLogin">Local Login</a>
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{screen.localLogin}}">
        login screen
    </template>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script>
(function() {
    Polymer({
        is: 'ws-auth',
        properties: {
            screen: {
                type: Object,
                notify: true
            }
        },
        attached: function() {
            if (!this.screen) {
                this.screen = {
                    initial: true
                }
            };
        },
        doLogin: function() {
            this.screen = {
                login: true
            }
        },
        doLocalLogin: function() {
            this.screen = {
                localLogin: true
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

When I click 'Local login' the first template isn't hidden. I expect it to be hidden, as I set the screen to a new object, which doesn't have the 'initial' attribute defined. There's another thing I struggle to understand: if I set the screen object to

```
{
     initial: false,
     localLogin: true
}
```

in the doLocalLogin() function, nothing at all happens.

Comment: Also, the expressions you can use in the if tag seem to be rather limited. Only properties seem to work, no function calls, '===' etc. Is that so?

Comment: Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/2w5ghun93mU3mSIzm8Ip?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the a sub property of an object, you need to use the [Polymer API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) - even when you would like to overwrite the whole object. You can either use `set` or `notifyPath`. To get your example to work I had to set `initial` to `false`.

```
doLocalLogin: function() {
    this.set("screen.localLogin", true);
    this.set("screen.initial", false);
}
```

Comment: Ah great thanks. I thought if I replace the whole object that'd do it. That's why I had this.screen = {} instead of setting individual parameters.

Comment: Cant get it working :) can you send me a link to your plunkr please?

Comment: I only modified the doLocalLogin function. You may need to use the same pattern in other places of your code as well.

Comment: Fantastic thanks. I think I've used the wrong lifecycle method (I used ready). Can you explain why it's not working with ready perhaps?

Comment: Ok I'll need to compare your version with mine :) Thanks, will update

Comment: Yes, it was the event.preventDefault(); that did the trick. If you remove that, a blank page is all you see after clicking the link. Why? :)

Comment: I think clicking the link causes the page to reload. preventDefault cancels that behaviour.

Comment: Makes complete sense. Thanks Maria.